# VSCode autocomplete is gone on new react project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

I'm struggling about this problem.

I used to work on a react project, on which autocomplete was working well, within react components, imports, packages from npm (react-query, hook-form, ...).

I just started a new project, and I can't get autocomplete on packages. I have the same extensions than before, the first project doesnt have any jsconfig.json, and both have the same eslint rules.

Any help would be appreciated !

PS : I restarted vscode several times

Thank's

Comment: Are you sure this is enabled for all workspaces?

Comment: I've been looking at vscode's settings to see any difference between both project, but I couldn't ... But I found a problem concerning my node_modules not being sync with my docker container, I guess it's a good trail i'm looking now

Comment: I can confirm, it's definitely all about my docker environment, my node modules aren't synced correctly. .. I will look at my volumes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my docker environment didn't synchronize node modules, then vscode couldn't find the libs in it.